# How to get all parent data for node?

Tags: javascript, jstree

My jstree parent code:

```
{"text": "PARENT GROUP (2022)", "data": {"level": 2022}, "children": [ {"text": "Some text.....
```

In code:

```
.bind("move_node.jstree", function (event, data)
```

How I can get level? in 'data' object I can't find this.